# What's different between these parameter vs injected Dispatchers?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

These two methods invoke the same use-case. In the first version, I hard-coded `Dispatchers.IO`, and things work as expected.

The second version (which I prefer) uses an injected dispatcher that defaults to the `Dispatchers.IO` type. It fails with the IllegalStateException described in the comments. Any ideas?

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getUsers: GetUsers,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
) : ViewModel() {
    val liveData: MutableLiveData<List<User>> = MutableLiveData()

    suspend fun getUsersByParamDispatcher(params: GetUsers.Params) {
        // Successfully works as intended.
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            getUsers(params).collectLatest {
                liveData.postValue(it)
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun getUsersByInjectDispatcher(params: GetUsers.Params) {
        // IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially
        // lock the UI for a long period of time.
        //   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:494).
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            getUsers(params).collectLatest {
                liveData.postValue(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logs confirm the exception and my curiosity is why are they different and how would I arrive at a working injected version.

Failing injected Dispatchers.IO:

`>> coroutine.name: main`

Working parameter Dispatchers.IO:

`>> coroutine.name: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1`

The dependencies are provided by [`@HiltViewModel`](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/hilt/android/lifecycle/HiltViewModel.html) and I expect dispatcher to respect its assigned default value. The Fragment creates this view model with the [`by viewModels()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#viewmodels) delegate.

It might be fine to hard-code the dispatcher. But with injection a blocking `TestCoroutineDispatcher` is easily passed during testing.

Maybe I'm overlooking something simple, or another way altogether.

```kotlin
// MainViewModelTest
@Before
fun setup() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this)

    viewModel = MainViewModel(
        getUsers,
        coroutinesTestRule.testDispatcher
    )
}
```

Comment: How Are you creating the ViewModel add the code with question ? You sure the CoroutineDispatcher injected is a IO try to print Thread name inside launch . Also add the code where you have Provider for Dispatcher .

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but dealing with dispatchers like that is not usually necessary. Room already has 1st-class support for suspend funs, where you just keep using the Main dispatcher, but even without that, hardcoding IO sounds completely fine.

Comment: Updated for @ADM and Marko.